# Handling non-existent routes in Rails 3.1 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I just switched to rails not long ago and I'm loving it. Everything works well in my rails 3.1 application, but now at the end I want to somehow handle routes like www.myapp.com/something (off course, I dont have something controller). I get a routing error when I visit this page, but I was wandering if there was a way to do something about it, even if it's only redirecting these routes to my root_url. I tried to find the answer online with no luck.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can put a globbing route at the very end of your `routes.rb` to catch all misses:

```
match '/*paths', :to => 'some_controller#some_action'
```

in your Controller / action you can access the globbed path with

```
params[:paths]
```

more information http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing

of course you can redirect without using an extra controller by using the `redirect` inline rack endpoint

```
match '/*paths' => redirect('/')
```